# How can I get the "signed-stream-name" from a turbo:before-stream-render event?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs, turbo, stimulus-rails

My project is using rails 7 with turbo streams and stimulus.

I'm trying to get the "signed-stream-name" as can be seen in the cable event:
[image]

However the "turbo:before-stream-render" that I want to intercept does not appear to include any of this information:

[image]

Does anyone know how I could get this attribute?

Answer (score 0):

```rb
<%= turbo_stream_from :users, id: "some_stream" %>
```

You could get it from a "message" event:

```js
document.querySelector("#some_stream").addEventListener("message", function (event) {
  console.log(event.target.channel.signed_stream_name);
})
```